# Jquery .find class not working

Tags: jquery, class, find

Why isn't this fiddle working?

http://jsfiddle.net/gupmgz0s/

I can't find the misstake in t his code does someone have a solution for this?

Thanks!

jquery:

```
$(".flip-container").find(".front").addClass("frontflip");


.flip-container:hover .front {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Does rotate the divs but when i use

```
.frontflip {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.backflip {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

with the right fiddle code above it doesnt?

Does someone have a idea?

Comment: are you trying to make it always rotated? or only when you hover over the html element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fiddle doesn't have `Jquery` included, now it's working:

```
$(".flip-container").find(".front").addClass("frontflip");
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/e63ycx2k/1/

Comment: weird i was pretty sure i included the jquery library so didn't check that again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`addClass` must have a capital 'C'

**Edit:**

In response to your rotation issue, it looks like it does work but your `frontflip` class does a 0 degree rotation so nothing happens. If you change the `addClass("frontflip")` to `addClass("backflip")` then you'll see some changes.

**See JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gupmgz0s/12/**

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) You need to include jquery library.

2) You have incorrect syntax for addclass method. it should be:

```
 $(".flip-container").find(".front").addClass("frontflip");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because you are not referencing jquery in **Frameworks & Extensions** section

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle is not working because you haven't included the Jquery in it.

and 'c' in addclass should be capital like 'addClass'

Answer (score 0):

```
.flip-container:hover .front {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Does rotate the divs but when i use

```
.frontflip {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.backflip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

with the right fiddle code above it doesnt?

Does someone have a idea?